# Operations on 1 Dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning operations on 1 dim array.

It has three parts:

1. Set the 10 elements of integer array counts to zero.
2. Add one to each of the 15 elements of integer array bonus.
3. Display the five values of integer array best Scores in column format.

I have already figured out the 3. I need help in figuring out 1 and 2.

This is my code:

```
public class OneDimArrayOperations {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        // a) Set the 10 elements of integer array counts to zero.
        int [] zeroArray = new int[10];
        for (int i = 10; i == 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Count to zero from 10 elements" + zeroArray);
        }

        // b) Add one to each of the 15 elements of integer array bonus.

        int [] arrayBonus = new int[15];
        for (int i = 0; i <arrayBonus.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Bonus array values "+ arrayBonus[i]);
        }


        //c) Display the five values of integer array bestScores in column format.
        int [] bestScores = {100,95,85,45,65};
        System.out.printf("%n%s%12s %n", "Value", "BestScores");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < bestScores.length ; counter++) {

            System.out.printf( "%d%9d%n" , counter , bestScores[counter]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use "standart" loop notation `for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)`

Comment: A "1 dimensional array" is simply an "array". In fact, all arrays in Java are 1-dimensional; 2 dimensional arrays are simply 1d arrays of 1d arrays.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. The line `int[] zeroArray = new int[10];` will create an int array of size 10 and initialise all elements to zero. That's the default behaviour in Java.
2. `for(int i = 0; i < arrayBonus.length; i++) { arrayBonus[i]++; }` will solve your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

part a:display:10,9,8,7,....1,0

```
for(int i=10;i>=0;i--)
```

part b:i havent understood your question

Comment: Please explain part b, so that I can help further

Comment: I needed to add 1 to all elements of array but i am getting 0 input from the code pasted above. How to add 1 to all the elements and displaying them.

Comment: for that you just need to add 1 before printing at the end:

Comment: System.out.println("Bonus array values "+ (arrayBonus[i] +1));

Comment: I am getting index out of bound exception according to your code at part 1.

Comment: what is your requirement in part 1?

Comment: to print 10 numbers you need to iterate 10 times. If u want to print from 10 to 0 then that makes 11 numbers so you need to initialize the array to int[] zeroArray=new int[11];

Comment: ok. then you just initialize the array to be that. int[] zeroArray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};